# How to create "Upcoming birthdays" module in Rails?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table "users" with a column "date_of_birth" (DATE format with day, month, year).
In frontend I need to list 5 upcoming birthdays.

Spent ages trying to work out the logic.. also browsed every possible article in Google with no luck..

Any suggestions how to do this in RoR?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the database?  If the answer is to be done there it will make a difference

Comment: Kathy - I'd say do it in the RoR model and avoid any DB specific SQL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several answers have suggested calculating/storing *day of year* and sorting on that, but this alone won't do much good when you're close to the end of the year and need to consider people with birthdays in the beginning of the next year.

I'd go for a solution where you calculate the full date (year, month, day) of each person's *next birthday*, then sort on that. You can do this in Ruby code, or using a stored procedure in the database. The latter will be faster, but will make your app harder to migrate to a different db platform later.

It would be reasonable to update this list of upcoming birthdays once per day only, which means you can use some form of caching. Thus the speed of the query/code needed is less of an issue, and something like this should work fine as long as you cache the result:

```
class User
  def next_birthday
    year = Date.today.year
    mmdd = date_of_birth.strftime('%m%d')
    year += 1 if mmdd < Date.today.strftime('%m%d')
    mmdd = '0301' if mmdd == '0229' && !Date.parse("#{year}0101").leap?
    return Date.parse("#{year}#{mmdd}")
  end
end

users = User.find(:all, :select => 'id, date_of_birth').sort_by(&:next_birthday).first(5)
```

**Edit**: Fixed to work correctly with leap years.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry to be a pain but I got an error when tried to implement this.

Here's from a log file:

NameError (undefined local variable or method `mmdd' for #<User id: 7, date_of_birth: "1984-05-01">):
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:260:in `method_missing'
    /app/models/user.rb:28:in `next_birthday'

Here's user.rb model: 
http://screencast.com/t/pYvUY5A6

Here's users_controller.rb:
http://screencast.com/t/vDRi3EkBZcM

And the view:
http://screencast.com/t/vvgQ5kEjic

Comment: I can't see why you should get that error. mmdd is only used as a variable local to the next_birthday method. Which line in user.rb is line 28?

I do see one mistake in your view though. You're using birthday_user as the loop variable, but are calling methods on user inside the loop. (Also, using each instead of for is more idiomatic Ruby.)

Comment: Ok, this is SO strange.. I spent at least two hours yesterday trying to make this work, no luck. Repeated the same today - WORKS NOW! And I did not amend anything.. At first it showed "unidentified xxxx" errors in log but then suddenly - just started to work. Still don't know why and how.. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to this post in my rails 3 app i use:

```
 u = User.where("strftime('%m%d', date_of_birth) = ?", Date.today.strftime('%m%d'))
```

Update:

To use this with Postgresql:

```
u = User.where("extract(month from date_of_birth) = ? AND extract(day from date_of_birth) = ?", Date.today.strftime('%m'), Date.today.strftime('%d'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use **SQL** to make this query:

```
next_month = (Date.today + 1.month).month # or use any other integer

users_having_birhtday_next_month = 
  User.where("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_of_birth) = ?", next_month)
```

Note: EXTRACT - PostgreSQL function

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a [before_save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M002429) callback that calculates and stores to the day of the year in the database alongside the birthday.

You then have a simple query to pull back the next 5 birthdays. Make sure to handle the boundary condition where you are at the end of the year (I'd check if you don't get 5 results in RoR and then run a new query for the 1st Jan to get some extra birthdays to make it up to 5).

You will probably want to cache the results so you don't keep rerunning the query if it is on a common page.

Answer (score 0):

I too thought that day of year would be the way to go, but the fact that it is different for most of the year depending on whether it is a leap year or not makes it tricky.

Better is to store the month and day as a string: d.strftime('%m%d').  You can then use that as (possibly) two queries (assuming new column is 'monthday')

First,

```
User.find(:all,
          :condition => [:monthday > Date.now.strftime('%m%d')],
          :select => "DISTINCT monthday",
          :limit => 5)
```

If you don't get 5 results, do the query again, except use "0101" instead of the date calculation and lower the limit.

This gets you a list of `monthday` strings that you then have to turn back into dates.

If you want users, remove the `:select` line.

Comment: RichH comments on before_save is how you calculate the string

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Oracle, you can do it without creating a new column. IMO it's a smell to create a column that contains data you already have.

The SQL's a bit ugly - I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do it. Generally in these cases I'd ask my DBA friends for advice.

```
User.find(:all,
  :conditions => 
    "TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dob, 'MMDD')) >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MMDD'))",
  :order => "TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dob, 'MMDD'))",
  :limit => 5)
```

Some people think a duplicate column is faster, but **if** you have enough user data that speed's an issue, you should benchmark the duplicate column against a table without it that has a functional index on `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dob, 'MMDD'))`.

Comment: How does this work during the last days of the year with less that 5 people's birthdays remaining in that same year?

Comment: That's such an edge case that I'd do a second query for it, rather than complicate the one that's used 99% of the time. Check the number of users that come back. If it's less than 5, do another User.find, no :conditions, same :order, :limit 5-x (where x is the number of users that came back from the first query).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I find today's birthdays:

`User.find_by_sql("select * from users where date_format(date_of_birth, '%m%d') = date_format(now(), '%m%d')"`)

I run this once a day. It takes less than a second from about 100,000 rows. (It doesn't properly handle people born on Feb 29th.)

Answer (score 0):

If your database is mysql, the following is probably faster:

```
scope :birthday_next_week, (lambda {
  where('DayOfYear(date_of_birth) >= 7
     And DayOfYear(date_of_birth) - DayOfYear(curdate()) Between 0 and 6) Or
   (MOD(YEAR(curDate()),4) = 0) And MOD(YEAR(curDate()),100) != 0
    And (DayOfYear(date_of_birth) + 366 - DayOfYear(curdate())) % 366 < 7) Or
     (DayOfYear(date_of_birth) + 365 - DayOfYear(curdate())) % 365 < 7').
    order('DATE_FORMAT( date_of_birth, "%m-%d" ) ASC')
})
```

Edit: changed to make it work in the week before new years eve / leap years.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me. I didn't require to filter the most recent five results, so I used month is same as current.

```
def upcoming_birthdays
    @resident = current_business.residents.where("extract(month from date_of_birth) = ?", Date.today.strftime('%m')).paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```