# How to select users with birthday around today in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to query all users who had their birthdays 1-2 days ago, who have their birthday today and in 1-2 days from now.

Is it possible to do it in pure rails way, without writing DB specific SQL queries?

User model is simple:
user_id, name, dob

There is a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056000/how-to-create-upcoming-birthdays-module-in-rails) but it's not exactly what I need.

Comment: Try sth. like this: User.find :dob => (Date.today..Date.today + 2.days)

Answer (score 6):

```
User.where(:dob => 2.days.ago .. 2.days.from_now)
```

Will result in a `WHERE dob BETWEEN 2_days_ago AND 2_days_from_now`

Comment: User.where(:dob => 2.days.ago .. 2.days.from_now)

Comment: The problem is that we usually store date of birth with actual birth year. (e.g. 12-Nov-1985) so this approach won't work

Comment: @iAndrew, 2.days.ago returns a date object. So the comparison includes the year part also. This solution should work.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu, 

User.select([:first_name, :birth_date]).last
 => #<User first_name: "Norma", birth_date: "1960-11-26">;

     User.select([:first_name, :birth_date]).where(:birth_date => 2.days.ago .. 30.days.from_now)
 => [] 

However I expect including this record into results, because Norma will have a birthday on 26th of November 2010

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem is. Unfortunately I do not see any way to break up a date in rails. You will need to drop to SQL and do 'MONTH(dob) BETWEEN ...' etc =(

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your comment. I'm going to utilize SQL query approach

Answer (score 1):

If you are to find people with birthday today then following will work(PG)

```
where("date_part('month', users.dob) = ? and date_part('day', users.dob) = ?", Date.current.month, Date.current.day)v
```

Answer (score -1):

I have one solution. Maybe it's not elegant, but it works for me:

```
@users=User.all

<% @users.each do |u| %>
    <% if u.dob+(Date.today.year-u.dob.year).years >= Date.yesterday && u.dob+(Date.today.year-u.dob.year).years <= Date.tomorrow %>
        <%= u.name %>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: you shouldn't do any logic like that in the view. There are two other places: a) in the model, make an new class method called 'User.recent_birthdays' which does all the prefiltering b) or if you really must you can add it to the controller. its really bad style as it is now, I'll remove my downvote if you reformat it...