# How to get earliest and latest dates for associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am developing an Rails 4 app and I got two models. One is called `Project` and the other is called `Task`.

`Project` has many `Tasks`.
`Task` belongs to `Project`.

The task objects have `starts_at` and `ends_at` attributes (datetime).
How can I get the earliest `starts_at` and latest `ends_at` of all the associated tasks that belongs to a specific project?

I tried `@project.tasks.max(:starts_at)` but it did not work (got error).

Comment: Use `maximum` instead of `max`. `max` is for array maximum: `[1,2].max`

Comment: Yes, it should be [`maximum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-maximum).

Comment: Worked fine! Please add your answer as a real answer and I will make it as correct.

Answer (score 4):

Use `maximum` instead of `max`.

`max` is for array maximum: `[1,2].max == 2`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-maximum

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from  [[Lars Haugseth's solution]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056000/how-to-create-upcoming-birthdays-module-in-rails) to find next birthdays.

model.rb

```
def latest_tasks
  todays_date = Date.today
  start_days_from_now = todays_date - starts_at
  ends_days_from_now = ends_at - todays_date
  if start_days_from_now < ends_days_from_now
    yearmmdd = starts_at.strftime('%Y%m%d')
  else
    yearmmdd = ends_at.strftime('%Y%m%d')
  end
  return Date.parse("#{yearmmdd}")
end
```

Controller.rb

```
@project.tasks.where('starts_at >= ? or ends_at >=? ', Date.today, Date.today).sort_by(&:latest_tasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for anyone looking to accomplish this, you could do it this way:

- Get an array of all the `starts_at` and `ends_at` values from `@project.tasks`:

  `starts_at_values = @project.tasks.pluck(:starts_at)`

  `ends_at_values = @project.tasks.pluck(:ends_at)`
- Select the `Task` record whose `starts_at` value is the earliest:

  `earliest_task = @project.tasks.select{|task| task.starts_at == starts_at_values.min}`
- Select the `Task` record whose `ends_at` value is the latest:

  `latest_task = @project.tasks.select{|task| task.starts_at == ends_at_values.max}`

If you need to only get the earliest and latest times, you could just do:

```
earliest_time = starts_at_values.min

latest_time = ends_at_values.max
```