# Rails how to display the earliest year (value) of the programs that the user belongs to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, min

I have a `program` table that `belongs_to userprofile` and `userprofile` table that `has_many programs`. The program has a program_year column and I wanted to display just the earliest year (value in that program_year) out of the programs if the user has multiple programs that he/she belongs to.

I have looked for similar questions and answers ([How to get earliest and latest dates for associated objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091778/how-to-get-earliest-and-latest-dates-for-associated-objects)). But can't seem to get my display working properly.

Having trouble understanding how to get the minimum program_year from programs for each userprofile. The code I have now..just gives me the minimum program_year of the current user and since it is in a loop. It displays the year x amount of times.

members_controller.rb

```
def index

  @userprofiles  = Userprofile.all
  # the use of current_user is incorrect..
  @member_program = Uprogram.where(:userprofile_id => current_user.userprofile.id).all 
  @member_since = @member_program.min

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% f.uprograms.each do |program| %>
  <% if program.present? %>
    <!-- just want to display the lowest program_year value) 
    Member since: <%= program.program_year %>
    <%= @member_since.program_year %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any insight would help! Thank you.

Comment: hey you can try this way by using mysql group `Userprofile.joins(:uprograms).group(:userprofile_id).select("user_profile.*,min(program_year) as member_since")`

Comment: @VishalJAIN hey, I'm not sure if I understand this fully. The code joins the programs and userprofile table by id? Then it returns the min of program_year based on userprofile as member_since? Does it belongs in the members_controller and stored in a variable? Then displayed in view? Sorry for having so many questions..

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas:

1- This will get you only the earliest `program_year` among all the user programs:

```
Uprogram.where(userprofile_id: current_user.userprofile.id).order(: program_year).limit(1).pluck(:program_year).first
```

2- This will give you the earliest `Uprogram` object:

```
current_user.userprofile.programs.order(:program_year).limit(1).first
```

Comment: Actually, I just noticed..the `current_user.userprofile.id` gives me the earliest `program_year` of the current_user..and it's displaying that year for all users which is incorrect. 

I was able to use: `@member_since = Uprogram.where(:userprofile_id => f.id).minimum(:program_year)` But it is used in the view.